# Editing Powerpoint Slide in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm trying to develop a Point of Purchase sign creator.
The best way that I can think of going about this is using a powerpoint slide to create the POP.

The problem that I'm having with this is I can find pages after pages of information to open up a presentation, but I can't seem to find anything that'll let me open the actual powerpoint file for editing. The client will not need to make new textboxes or anything of that sort, but will need to be able to edit them.

Currently I'm using a web browser to view the ppt presentation but as I mentioned, it is merely a presentation.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("about.blank");
        string path = "C:\\Users\\Test\\test.ppt";
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
    }
```

Thank you in advance

p.s. I do have Office Interop referenced in the project but it seems that everything is so situationally specific that I cannot find much information to help me out.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is the scope of "editing" that you are looking at?

Comment: So, let me get this straight... You're creating software that edits power point presentations by using Office interop to edit power point presentations?

Comment: @Will this is not that unreasonable since this is to be used in a very specific situation.

Comment: exactly as BrianLy explained. A more detailed description of what i'm trying to do is on the comment of BrianLy's answer

Comment: @Brian @Erick So you're actually "editing" in the form of switching out text in a template.  Got it.  BTW, I'm doing something very similar, but instead of using a PPT as a template, I'm using WPF Pages and UserControls, binding against my data and then printing it using the XPS print path.  Might be too complex if you expect users to create and supply the PPT.

Comment: @Will Actually the user will not have to supply anything other than the UPC of the item they need the sign for. It may be too complex for me though haha. I have very little programming experience but I'm learning as I go. I do not know much (or anything) about WPF pages. Would this be a better option for me?

Comment: @Erick If you're a beginner, PPT may be too complex.  The WPF solution would most definitely be too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you could provide a little more info on exactly how flexible the editing needs to be, and what version of PowerPoint you are targeting. From your question and approach you appear to be looking for access to all of the capabilities. This is not something that you are going to be able to do easily with your approach.

A few other options which might work for you:

1. Use the [Open XML format and generate the PPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465.aspx#CreateDocswithOpenXMLSDK_CreatingaPresentationReportBasedonData) from an external data source. This seems a lot cleaner to me but you have less flexibility than your current approach. You would need to capture user's changes yourself and then generate the file to preview.
2. Copy a PPT file to a temp file and open it in PowerPoint for editing. Then allow the user to edit and update it. When they close the temp file capture it and bring them back to your main application. The user has full access to the PPT file to do what they want but you have a lot of edge cases to handle. eg. what if they close the file and don't exit PowerPoint etc.
3. Write a PowerPoint add-in that works with your application, and make some Ribbon customisations. The user will get the full PowerPoint experience but there will be custom support for your application on the Ribbon and the user can just click to have the finished PPT sent back to your application. This seems like it would be more maintainable than option 2 since you are probably going to use more standard APIs and a user has to click your "finish" button to complete the process meaning that you have a clearly defined end point instead of watching for user behaviour that you could miss.

Comment: Well to describe what i'm trying to is have a powerpoint template that gets it's textbox values from a database. I've figured out this much on my own. The only editing that the user will be doing is the occasional text editing. For example, if the database has a shortened description, I'd like the user to be able to edit it to show the full description. It would be great for it to be user friendly enough that they can just click on the text that needs to be edited and edit it, as if they were doing so in powerpoint. And Finally I'd need it to print from the form, which I think I can figure out

Comment: And I'm using office 2010. I believe it's Powerpoint 14 in my references

Comment: I think options 2/3 are the only ones which will do what you want but I'd like to be wrong. Please post another comment if you find a better solution.